# Echo author slug in post edit page

Tags: posts, php, author, slug

On the Post edit page in the back-end, how do I echo the author's `user_nicename`? I am referring to the author of the post, not current user.

Comment: Can you edit the solution out and put it in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
global $post;
$author_id=$post->post_author;
the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this because I needed to do this, I would advise against accessing the global like this I used this.

```
get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename', get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) )
```